# Convert String to Sql date in spring framework

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, postman

So I want to convert a String data from controller, and convert it to sql date format so it can fit in to my posgresql database. Here is my code :

```
@Override
public Integer simpleUpdate(String user, String departemen, String dob, String id)
{
    Date date=Date.valueOf(dob);
    String sql="UPDATE public.kantor SET nama = ?, departemen = ?, dob = ?, WHERE id = ?";    
    Integer result = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, user, departemen, date, Integer.parseInt(id));
    return result;
}
```

But it resulted in this error:

```
"timestamp": 1615124585085,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
"message": "No message available"
```

on my postman.

Comment: Your SQL is incorrect because you have a comma before the `WHERE`.  Don't know if that is causing the problem you are seeing, though.

Comment: You should validate and convert the string to a date at the point the program receives it, in the controller, not in the code that talks to the database. That way the controller can validate the inputs, return an error message for bad inputs, and not pass garbage through, and the application can have meaningful types to deal with instead of strings.

Comment: @NathanHughes so i have to change it like this ? String doob = body.get("dob");
        Date date=Date.valueOf(doob);
        Integer cDet = crudService.simpleUpdate(user, departemen, date, id);

Comment: Yes like that. Do you still have an issue after fixing the comma typo?

Comment: Nah, it's all good now, thank you very much @NathanHughes